# What word is « qu' » in « qu'à l'oral » ?

Tags: grammaire

I would like to know what word is « qu' » in « qu'à l'oral ».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a contraction of "que à l'oral" which in French sounds awkward because of the following *e* and *à*. It means *orally only*.

Answer (score 7):

The word **que** has indeed several meanings.

In this context, “que” is an **adverb** in sense of *limitation* or *restriction*. The word **seulement** could be used in that case too. Then, you must have noticed the presence of **ne** before, in the same clause.

If “que” has been replaced by “qu'” in this particular context, it's because the “e” elides before a vowel.

For instance, these sentences are equivalent:

> Je **ne** suis interrogé **qu'** à l'oral.
>   Je suis interrogé **seulement** à l'oral.
>   Je suis interrogé **uniquement** à l'oral.